# Private Typescript library as an npm depenency

Tags: git, typescript, npm, gitlab-ci, yarnpkg

I have a Typescript library that I package as an npm module. I have integrated this library easily using `yarn link` during my development of a frontend application.

Now is the time to setup GitLab CI and let other developers work on the frontend application. I am currently running into the problem of distributing this package.

The options I have identified and the problems I encounter:

- `yarn add <git-url>`

This adds the source code, but as it is typescript, this is uncompiled. I am not able to compile this library using the same `tsconfig.json`. Only a single file gets compiled.

This solution further has the problem that port :22 is blocked on the developer's machines. That would prevent them from using `git+ssh`. I do not see how CI would be able to retrieve this package that would also work for the developers.

- `yarn add tar-ball`

I tried using a tarball, but there is no obvious way of storing this tarball. GitLab does not expose artifacts produced from builds to other CI pipelines.

- vendoring the package

Next, I decided to try to add the node module to the git repo. But I have found no way of preventing yarn to auto remove this package. If I add the library to `node_modules`  then it gets removed when running `yarn`.

Of course, I can switch to using a private npm module. But it seems to me that there should be easy alternatives for internal packages to get distributed if you already have a perfectly fine GitLab environment.

How can I distribute a Typescript package privately without a NPM private registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to vendor the package but put it in a custom directory (not under `node_modules`), for example `my-library`, and then in the `dependencies` in `package.json`, write `"my-library": "link:my-library"`.  This will cause Yarn to create a symlink from `node_modules/my-library` to `my-library`.  See [this thread](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2165) for more information about the `link:` syntax.